# Disconnecting LAN cable will disconnect Hyper-V shared network

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have 2 servers, both are connected to the internet with a 1 GBps network cable. Also both servers have a direct 10 GBps connection to eachother. In both servers I've created 2 virtual switches:

1. WAN - Connected to the 1 GBps internet connection
2. LAN - Connected to the internal 10 GBps connection

Both switches are shared with the management operating systems.

Hosted on the servers are 3 virtual machines each, all share the LAN connection and only 1 is connected to the WAN connection.

[image]

Yesterday I had to do upgrades to one of the servers, so I disconnected the LAN cable between the servers, but this caused the full connection between all virtual machines to be disconnected causing the whole network to fail. All virtual machines showed the message "network disconnected" on the LAN connections.

[image]

To solve this, I ended up setting the LAN virtual switch to "internal virtual switch", this didn't change the connectivity. After shutting down all virtual machines, restarting the host, then turning on all virtual machines again, the network was up again.

I've looked around in the settings of the virtual switch and did some googling, but I cannot find out how to prevent this from happening?

I also tried this at home, but this does not happen, when I unplug my LAN connection the virtual machines keep being connected. The difference between home and the servers is a different network adaptor, cheap external 1GBps network adaptor @ home vs. professional 10GBps Intel X520-DA2, and Windows Server 2016 @ home vs. Windows 10 Pro.

FYI, all virtual machines are Windows Server 2016, and the hosts are Windows 10 Pro (because of driver issues).

Comment: Just in case you are experiencing an issue with the network disconnection causing the interfaces connected to the LAN side going to public or whatever, look over this answer I posted: https://superuser.com/questions/1283316/stop-windows-nla-from-repeatedly-detecting-local-network-as-a-new-unidentified/1284961#1284961 for a solution to resolve that does not require a restart of the host Hyper-V server. This may be worth a read and/or a test in your case just in case. I know this is for Server 2012 R2 but it may apply to Server 2016 as well—check it out and I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: How do you prevent this from happening? Don't do what you did. Migrate the VM's off of the host you want to perform maintenance on, then perform your maintenance. Then reverse that for the other host.